# Duplicate tags: [vue.js] and [vue-js]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tags [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) and [vue-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-js) are referencing the same framework. The last one created is the [vue-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-js) tag with only eight questions. Should the tags be merged?

Comment: Seems pretty clearcut, even the wiki's are identical. There are only 8 questions -- If no one objects, I can take care of them and replace all [vue-js] with [vue.js].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've replaced all instances of [vue-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-js) with [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) and removed the unecessary tag from posts which had both.  I'll also keep an eye on the tag and ensure the roomba deletes it.

Comment: It seems like the issue is present as of now. Also see this post from June: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326127/merge-vuejs-into-vue-js

Comment: Both tags are back