# Merge [vuejs] into [vue.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) and [vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) are two tags that refer to the same library. The tag wikis are nearly identical ([`vuejs`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vuejs/info), [`vue.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vue.js/info)).

I propose making [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) the master, since [the library's documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/README.md) spells it "Vue.js" with the dot.

Comment: I knew I had seen this before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318023/duplicate-tags-vue-js-and-vue-js

Comment: One question remaining in the [vuejs]-tag... Tags get automatically deleted by a script when they're inactive for a while, right?

Comment: Still alive and kicking, [tag:vuejs] has a huge 20 pages of questions now. Well, damn...

Comment: Does not sound like a dupe to me. *This* question essentially asks to revert what happened *there*.