# Merge tags: [vuejs] [vue.js] [vuejs2] [vue2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

There are many duplicates tags on vue.js. Especially now v.2.0 is released (and very similar to v.1):

- [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)
- [vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs)
- [vue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue2)
- [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2)

I would suggest to keep only [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js).

Comment: Related [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357753/merge-vue-js-into-vuejs), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318023/duplicate-tags-vue-js-and-vue-js)

Comment: [tag:vuejs] and [tag:vue2] are now gone, only [tag:vuejs2] is left

Comment: Synonymized [vuejs] -> [vue.js]; [vue2] -> [vuejs2].