# Merge [vue.js] into [vuejs]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think we should merge the tags [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) and [vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) together.

[image]

There is a [vuejs2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs2) for v2, but both the above point to the same version. So, I suggest we should merge them into [vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) as is the case for other popular libraries such as Angular, React, etc.

On second thought, I think both should be merged to just [vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue).

Comment: Can you provide an argument for *why* these tags should be merged, preferably one that is based on the posts that actually have these tags? Just looking at the tag description is not sufficient. Tags get misused all the time. Are these two tags actually being used in practice to describe the exact same library? If so, a merge would certainly be appropriate.

Comment: Well, the synonym got approved, despite this proposal having more downvotes than upvotes, and no rationale, but apparently that's what the people knowledgeable in the tag think is best, so this is now [[meta-tag:status-completed]].

Comment: @CodyGray I think people downvoted because of 2nd part of request: renaming all of this to [tag:vue]

Comment: Nope. I added that after the down votes begun. Sadly, that's what this site has turned into. I even had a bunch of comments that didn't break the rules rules with no justification or explanation. Let the mods do what they need I guess.

Comment: We regularly remove comments that ask about downvotes, as they serve no purpose. If people wanted to leave comments about their disagreement, then they would have done so. They didn't, and they're gone, so asking them why is not useful; it's just noise. We also deleted some rude comments from community members, telling you that you had no idea what Meta is for (clearly you do), and then we deleted some obsolete comments about what the purpose of Meta is. I don't know what you mean by "that's what this site has turned into". Somewhere where the community discusses things? Yes... Always has been

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in reading [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s). It's even more true on Meta, where downvotes serve simply as markers of disagreement. I'm not sure why you are attacking moderators here. I merely asked you to provide a justification for why this should be done. If you can convince a moderator, then we can do tag manipulation single-handedly, quickly and efficiently. That's why I was asking, because I'm trying to help.